# Shell script if statement compraising of string comparision and boolean check

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, if-statement, sh

I have a function where in I'm trying to compare the first parameter to a string, and then a separate boolean variable.

**My sample bools:**

```
EMS=true; 
COLL=true;
```

At a given point, both or any one or none of them can be true.

**My function body:**

```
function some_function() {
...
...
     if [ [ "$1" = "ez" ] &&  $EMS ] || [ "$1" = "coll" ] &&  $COLL ]; then
     #do mysterious magic
     ...
     ...
fi
}
```

**I'm calling the function like so:**

```
some_function ez
some_function coll
```

However when I execute the script, I run into this:

```
./deployBuild.sh: line 145: [: too many arguments
```

My if loop is incorrect and I'm unable to fix it. How do I proceed with?

**Pseudo code of what I want to achieve:**

```
if ("$1" is "ez" AND $EMS evaluates to true) OR ("$1" is "coll" AND $COL evaluates to true)
```

Comment: Also, you can't wrap `[` -- I added another duplicate which (indirectly) explains this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@xaiwi gave you the right answer: use `[[` instead of `[` -- check [Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs)
in the bash manual.

Your logic is wrong though:

```
if [[ ( "$1" = "ez" &&  $EMS ) || ( "$1" = "coll"  &&  $COLL) ]];
```

With the value `$EMS` *inside* the `[[...]]`, you get a "true" result if the value is **non-empty** -- see `-n` in [Conditional Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) in the manual

Since "true" is a bash command, you probably want one of

```
if ([[ $1 = "ez" ]] &&  $EMS) || ([[ $1 = "coll" ]] && $COLL); then ...
if { [[ $1 = "ez" ]] &&  $EMS; } || { [[ $1 = "coll" ]] && $COLL; }; then ...
```

The first one uses subshells for command grouping; the second uses the current-shell grouping syntax -- [reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping).

Answer (score 1):

In recent Bash, you can try :

```
if  [[  ( "$1" = "ez"   &&  $EMS ) || (  "$1" = "coll"  &&  $COLL ) ]]
```

More portable solution is:

```
if  [  \( "$1" = "ez"   -a  $EMS \) -o \(  "$1" = "coll"  -a  $COLL \) ]
```